# LibGit2Sharp security vulnerabilities

Tags: git, owasp, libgit2, libgit2sharp

I have done a OWASP Dependency Check and found few vulnerabilities in LibGit2Sharp nuget package.these are as follows-

1) CVE-2014-9938
contrib/completion/git-prompt.sh in Git before 1.9.3 does not sanitize branch names in the PS1 variable, allowing a malicious repository to cause code execution.
CWE-116 Improper Encoding or Escaping of Output

2) CVE-2015-7082

Multiple unspecified vulnerabilities in Git before 2.5.4, as used in Apple Xcode before 7.2, have unknown impact and attack vectors.  NOTE: this CVE is associated only with Xcode use cases.

3) CVE-2015-7545

The (1) git-remote-ext and (2) unspecified other remote helper programs in Git before 2.3.10, 2.4.x before 2.4.10, 2.5.x before 2.5.4, and 2.6.x before 2.6.1 do not properly restrict the allowed protocols, which might allow remote attackers to execute arbitrary code via a URL in a (a) .gitmodules file or (b) unknown other sources in a submodule.
CWE-20 Improper Input Validation, CWE-284 Improper Access Control

I have looked into LibGit2Sharp security updates but could not find if they were fixed in the latest package. I am new to this security domain so I am unable to determine if these issue concern our project . And if they were already resolved or not.

I have also looked into LibGit2 library security updates also as LibGit2Sharp is built over it. But i was unable to find anything related to these vulnerabilities.

Could someone shed some light in this regard?

Comment: Libgit2 does not use git code, so git vulnerabilities are not relevant. There may be analogous, but they would have different numbers

Comment: CVE-2019-1351: is a git vulnerability which has been fixed in latest LibGit2Sharp release. So, there might be more git vulnerabilities that are not fixed in LibGit2Sharp. Yes , it doesn't use any of the git code but it still does not clear to me why these are shown as the vulnerabilities by OWASP scan.